# Filtering characters entered into a UITextField

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField in my application. I'd like to restrict the set of characters that can be can be entered into the field to a set that I have defined. I could filter the characters entered into the field when the text is committed using the UITextFieldDelegate method:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField*)textField
```

However, this gives the user a false impression as although restricted characters are removed from the final value, they were still visibly entered into the text field before pressing Return/Done/etc. What is the best approach that would prevent restricted characters appearing in the text field as they are selected on the keyboard?

**Note:** I am operating under the assumption that I have little control over which keys are provided by the iPhone keyboard(s). I am aware that I can switch between various keyboard implementations but am under the impression that I can't disable specific keys. This assumption may be incorrect.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Look at `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange`

This method is called by the `UITextFieldDelegate` whenever new characters are typed or existing characters are deleted from the text field.  You could return NO to not allow the change.

Comment: Sample code to this answer can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013647/filtering-characters-entered-into-a-uitextfield/1015262#1015262

Comment: Nice job adding URL to your answer which is right below this one. +1

Answer (score 25):

I did as marcc suggested and it worked well. Sample implementation follows.

**Note:** Variable names were selected for brevity and do not reflect my coding standards:

```
    ...
    myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"xyzXYZ"];
    ...
}

- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered {
    for (int i = 0; i < [textEntered length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
            return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: it is unnecessary to iterate through all the characters in textEntered. you can just check unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:[textEntered length] - 1]; you dont need the for loop

Comment: and you also need to make sure it returns yes when backspace character is entered

Comment: @PatrickAnarna: checking the last character is not sufficient. `textEntered` could be a pasted chunk of text with more than one character.

Comment: making myCharset = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"xyzXYZ\b"]; will allow for backspaces

Answer (score 4):

Here is one of the cleanest approaches to restricting characters entered in a UITextField.  This approach allows the use of multiple predefined NSCharacterSets.

```
-(BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string{

    NSMutableCharacterSet *allowedCharacters = [NSMutableCharacterSet alphanumericCharacterSet];
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    [allowedCharacters formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet symbolCharacterSet]];

    if([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:allowedCharacters.invertedSet].location == NSNotFound){

        return YES;

    }

    return NO;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `UITextViewDelegate` method `- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string`.

It's exactly what you need.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to restrict the user to uppercase A-Z.  Adjust the regex variable according to taste:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString* regex = @"[^A-Z]";
    return ([string rangeOfString: regex
                      options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location == NSNotFound);
};
```

Comment: The semicolon after "regex" should not be there.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    NSString* regex = @"[^a-z]";
    return ([[string lowercaseString] rangeOfString: regex
                      options:NSRegularExpressionSearch].location == NSNotFound);
};
```

Note:

I am making all characters to lower case `[string lowercaseString]` so that you don't need to write in regex for captial/small letters.

Answer (score -6):

You could loop and keep checking if the UITextField.text property has changed once the DidBeginEditing method gets called.  If it has, check the text and remove an bad characters.