# only character - not special/numbers from keyboard - iPhone

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uikeyboard

Normal `UITextField` displays a `UIKeyboard` which includes alpha+Numberic+specials

But I need alpha only...

I need this because if user enters something like --  A'bad

it has a char '  -- which is affecting my query .

How we can set only `alphabetic` `UIKeyboard` to user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This SO post answers your question:
[UIkeyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117980/uikeyboard-type)

Answer (score 2):

I think. I got the answer.

In your `UIViewController` file **.h** add `delegate<UITextfieldDelegate>`

Now add following code to **.m** file

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField 
         shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
         replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered {

    for (int i = 0; i < [textEntered length]; i++) {
        unichar c = [textEntered characterAtIndex:i];
        if (![myCharSet characterIsMember:c]) {
           return NO;
        }
    }
    return YES;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Instead of disabling or not allowing user to add '(apostorpe) use following code, it will allow you to insert '(apostorpe)

```
[textEntered stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" ' " withString:@" ' '"];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use as i do below;

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)field shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)characters
{
    NSMutableCharacterSet *filteredChars = [NSMutableCharacterSet letterCharacterSet];
    [filteredChars formUnionWithCharacterSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];
    NSCharacterSet *blockedCharSet = [filteredChars invertedSet];
    if (([string rangeOfCharacterFromSet:blockedCharSet].location == NSNotFound)) {
          return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```