# add a .com button to keyboard like safari

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I want to add a .com button to my basic keyboard like safari gives when a user types in a textbox.  Is this possible to do without some insane amount of coding?  And if so, how?  Searches on google haven't proven to be too informative.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is rather simple you will have to do the following

```
//field is the UITextField outlet you have in your viewcontroller
field.keyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeURL;
```

read more from

[UIkeyboard type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117980/uikeyboard-type)

Comment: Wow, no idea it was so easy.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`keyboardType` property is your friend. Set it to `UIKeyboardTypeURL`. You can do it either in code or in Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

It's in Apple's documentation for the iOS platform. The keyboard you're looking for is the URL specific keyboard. Read up on the matter [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html)

By the way: It's the second result for [my google search](https://www.google.no/webhp?hl=en&tab=ww#hl=en&newwindow=1&safe=off&sclient=psy-ab&q=.com+keyboard+ios&oq=.com+keyboard+ios&aq=f&aqi=q-A3&aql=&gs_l=hp.3..33i29l3.22626.22815.1.22986.3.3.0.0.0.0.109.249.2j1.3.0...0.0.v9dWhXXXEfA&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=d2f5f37bb887a40c&biw=1483&bih=934)