# TextField with UITextContentType emailAddress dose not behave like email text field

Tags: swiftui

When using an email text field, I expect (at minimum) that text will not be uppercased and spell check will be disabled.
When using:

```
TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.userEmail)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
```

Both the first letter is capitalized and spell check is working. This force me to use:

```
TextField("Email", text: $viewModel.userEmail)
                    .textContentType(.emailAddress)
                    .autocapitalization(.none) // redundant?
                    .disableAutocorrection(true) // redundant?
```

What then is the meaning of using `emailAddress`?
The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextcontenttype/1649660-emailaddress) is of course clearing this all up:

> A property that defines the content in a text input area as an email address.

That's just noise. I couldn't have guessed that `emailAddress` *"defines the content as an email address"*...
So what does `emailAddress` **actually** do?

Comment: Found more (not really an answer tho) in the documentation stating: Use this property to give the keyboard and the system information about the expected semantic meaning for the content that users enter. For example, you might specify emailAddress for a text field that users fill in to receive an email confirmation. When you provide this information about the content you expect users to enter in a text input area, the system can in some cases automatically select an appropriate keyboard and improve keyboard corrections and proactive integration with other text input opportunities.

Comment: It was already once, in a similar manner, asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117980/uikeyboard-type No duplicate as the initial question is different.

Comment: Was the question answered or is this still open?

Comment: So the takeaway from this is that `emailAddress` does very little, and **does not** either disable autocapitalization or correction. So adding them both is needed still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `UIKit.UITextInputTraits` you can find that `emailAdress` defines the `UIKeyboardType` enum with value `7` stating:

```
case emailAddress = 7 // A type optimized for multiple email address entry (shows space @ . prominently).
```