# allow only to enter english characters in iPhone UITextField

Tags: ios, uitextfield

I want to allow user to enter only english alphabets and characters. How can i prevent user from entering other characters than english.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013647/filtering-characters-entered-into-a-uitextfield

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out UIKeyboardType - there is an option to support only ASCII (UIKeyboardTypeASCIICapable).

Also, there are options in the UITextFieldDelegate protocol that could allow you to selectively filter input. Take a look at:

`- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string;`