# Validate textfield with special character

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4

In my app. I want to validate textfield with Special characters,

Ex.
if user press the ? from keypad than user not able to enter the ? in Textfield,

Please any one suggest, How can i do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try like below it will help you.It will accept only letters

```
   - (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
    {
        //For avoiding user to enter non digital number..
        if([[string stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[[NSCharacterSet letterCharacterSet] invertedSet]] isEqualToString:@""])
        {
            return NO;
        }
        else
        {
            return YES;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1013647/filtering-characters-entered-into-a-uitextfield)

use

```
- (BOOL) textField:(UITextField*)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString*)textEntered
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this works :

```
    -(NSString *) formatIdentificationNumber:(NSString *)string
     {
       NSCharacterSet * invalidNumberSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"\n_!@#$%^&*()[]{}'\".,<>:;|\\/?+=\t~` "];

    NSString  * result  = @"";
    NSScanner * scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string];
    NSString  * scannerResult;

    [scanner setCharactersToBeSkipped:nil];

     while (![scanner isAtEnd])
     {
    if([scanner scanUpToCharactersFromSet:invalidNumberSet intoString:&scannerResult])
    {
        result = [result stringByAppendingString:scannerResult];
    }
    else
    {
        if(![scanner isAtEnd])
        {
            [scanner setScanLocation:[scanner scanLocation]+1];
        }
    }
 }

  return result;
  }
```